# Docker swarm deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I have problem with Azure - i am missing `Docker for azure CE` in `Microsoft Azure Marketplace`. By this tutorial

https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/cloud-swarm/link-azure-swarm/#enable-your-azure-subscription-for-docker-cloud

it was there.
I followed the tutorial and i have local swarm running on my OS (which is Ubuntu). How can i deploy my local swarm to `Azure` some other way?
I cannot continue the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Cloud is shutting down in a few weeks, so I don't recommend using it or its custom OS builds.  It's quite easy to build a Swarm with the "[Docker for Azure](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/)" template, or by scratch by just creating Azure resources yourself and installing [Docker on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Comment: I've undersootd and followed the first link you provied - but how can i deploy to `Azure` swarm from my localhost? I have swarm running on localhost on `docker-machine`

Comment: Are you asking how to connect a docker cli to a remote engine? https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Comment: You can also use docker-machine to spin up Azure VM's and let it manage remote TLS certs for easy remote cli

Comment: I gave you upvote, but you did not fully understood my question - i made better question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240972/deployment-docker-compose-to-azure-using-cli-timeout