# Deployment with docker-compose to Azure using CLI gives timeout when visiting agent page

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, docker-compose, azure-container-service

I have `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app2:
    image: kamilwit/dockerdocker_app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ./app2
    volumes:
      - app2data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
  app:
    image: kamilwit/dockerdocker_app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - app1data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
volumes:
  app1data:
  app2data:
```

I followed the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-swarm-walkthrough

To be exact I executed the following commands:

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location westus

az acs create --name mySwarmCluster --orchestrator-type Swarm --resource-group myResourceGroup --generate-ssh-keys --agent-count 1
```

then I got the `output` from

```
az network public-ip list --resource-group myResourceGroup --query "[*].{Name:name,IPAddress:ipAddress}" -o table

Name                                                            IPAddress
--------------------------------------------------------------  --------------
swarm-agent-ip-myswarmclu-myresourcegroup-76f1d9agent-EEACED89  104.42.144.82
swarm-master-ip-myswarmclu-myresourcegroup-76f1d9mgmt-EEACED89  104.42.255.141
```

I connect to ssh with: 
`ssh -p 2200 -fNL 2375:localhost:2375 azureuser@104.42.255.141`
i use:

`export DOCKER_HOST=:2375`

then I started my docker-compose file:
`docker-compose up -d`

The output of `docker ps` is:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
3bfff4427e44        kamilwit/dockerdocker_app    "/bin/sh /data/app..."   18 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        10.0.0.5:8001->8080/tcp   swarm-agent-EEACED89000001/app
c297ea34547e        kamilwit/dockerdocker_app2   "/bin/sh /data/app..."   18 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        10.0.0.5:8000->8080/tcp   swarm-agent-EEACED89000001/app2
```

However I am unable to connect to my site by `ip` from `agent` in the example above I tried going to
`104.42.144.82:8000`
and `104.42.144.82:8001/#!/registration`
or even `10.0.0.5:8000`

I get a time out. When i run this dockerfile locally, I connect like that to my sites:
`localhost:8000`
and `localhost:8001/#!/registration`

Tried on

```
az --version
azure-cli (2.0.32)
```

I tried opening ports in `Azure`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/37zIm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J868P.jpg

But that did not help.
I tried also opening the site from mobile phone (another network on it) did not help.

**Edit:**

using `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app2:
    image: kamilwit/dockerdocker_app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ./app2
    volumes:
      - app2data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
  app:
    image: kamilwit/dockerdocker_app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - app1data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
volumes:
  app1data:
  app2data:
```

and following the same steps from the question I can access first site on port 80, but i can not access site on port 8001.
If i changed port from 8001 to 80, and leave 8000 - then i can access to the site on port 80 but no on the site on port 8000.

Comment: Did you try with `104.42.255.141:8001` also?

Comment: @TarunLalwani You can run locally my images (they are public) to see that it does not matter. Even `:8000` did not work.

Comment: Oh, so you mean locally also the stuff is not working?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no, locally it works fine. You can check it

Comment: The concern is the cloud here, so we need to see why it doesn't work. That's why I asked can you check port `8001` on both the IPs you had. Because you mentioned you only checked `104.42.144.82:8000`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I will check the port soon - and update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170847/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-yami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if your docker image works in azure, and you can open web page from swarm master server.

```
ssh -p 2200 azureuser@104.42.255.141 # Connect via ssh to your swarm master
sudo apt-get install lynx # Install lynx - console web browser 
docker ps # check IP address of app
lynx 10.0.0.5:8000 # Open your app in lynx (using private IP address)
```

If page doesn't load then there is a problem with the image or your app didn't start properly.
If page loads, it means there is a problem with network infrastructure. Probably there is missing rules in load balancer for swarm agent. By default, there are open ports at `80`, `443` and `8080`. Just add new rule for `8000`, and wait a moment.

Comment: `load balancer` was the issue